# Split table into different level columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have got a requirement to split the data based on the level into 3 different columns. In the below table SU_DC_1 is the top level based on SETTLEUNIT column   I need to add the level.

Parent : TOPSETTLUNIT
Child  : SETTLEUNIT

Based on Child I need to create 3 additional columns

[image: Input Table]

In the above hierarchy is mentioned as 
[image]

- **Output:**

[image]

I am finding it difficult to write the query for it. Could you please help .

Comment: Please write an example that replaces the cryptic abbreviations/codes with something understandable.

Comment: Do you have any unique column on your first table or based on which column we need to construct another table? Please explain a bit more

Comment: @Kalyan I  dont have unique identifier on first table . Based on SETTLEUNIT column i need to derive the table 2

Comment: @xsquared I have updated the question. Not sure if it understandable now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT topsettlunit,
       settleunit,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( topsettlunit ) AS level1,
       CASE LEVEL
         WHEN 1 THEN settleunit
         WHEN 2 THEN topsettlunit
       END AS level2,
       CASE LEVEL
         WHEN 2 THEN settleunit
       END AS level3
FROM   your_table
START WITH topsettlunit NOT IN ( SELECT settleunit FROM your_table )
CONNECT BY PRIOR settleunit = topsettlunit;
```