# Create columns based on the level on another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is similar to the question i created

[Split table into different level columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903329/split-table-into-different-level-columns/44903985#44903985)

I have two tables one which indicates the level of SETTLUNIT and one the raw data. By comparing one table i have to create 3 new columns .

like

**Table 1 :**

[image]

**Table 2 :**

[image]

By seeing the level from table 1 i need to add 3 columns in table 2.

If it is level 2 i need to bring level 1 and level 2 and so on.

**Output:** Row 1 has only level 1 and level 2 because it has level as 2 in master level table.

[image]

Could you please help me how to create a query . I tried with UNION but some how not getting the required output

Comment: How do you know which level 2 goes with which level 3?

Comment: @GordonLinoff First I need to check the master level table if it is level 2 I need to update level 1 and level 2 in table 2 . If it is level 3 I need to update level 1,level2,level 3 columns in table 2

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a pivot query:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pivot_examples.htm

https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot - you do not have any way of knowing how the hierarchy is organised and which parent is associated with which children.

Is it:

```
SU_DC_1
 ├ SU_SP_1
 │ ├ SU_PZ_012
 │ └ SU_PZ_1
 └ SU_SP_2
```

or:

```
SU_DC_1
 ├ SU_SP_1
 │ └ SU_PZ_012
 └ SU_SP_2
   └ SU_PZ_1
```

or:

```
SU_DC_1
 ├ SU_SP_1
 │ └ SU_PZ_1
 └ SU_SP_2
   └ SU_PZ_012
```

or:

```
SU_DC_1
 ├ SU_SP_1
 └ SU_SP_2
   ├ SU_PZ_012
   └ SU_PZ_1
```

And with more identifiers the number of possible hierarchical relationships is just going to increase exponentially.

You need to store the hierarchical relationship between the levels and then you could get the output you require - at the moment there is not enough information to do this.